# Entity Framework and Table Relationships

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm using VS 2013 and EF6 to build an MVC app and having trouble understanding the behavior I'm seeing.

**My database looks like this**
[image: Database]

I try adding a new order, via the model generated by EF:

```
ResourceType resource = new ResourceType();
resource.ID = 2;
resource.Name = "Van"
order.resourceType().Add(resource)

db.Orders.Add(order);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Everything works ok, but in the database I see new ResourceType records being created with a random ID.

I'm expecting that ResourceType is just a reference/lookup table used when ResourceType_Order, translating to the resource type name.

For each order, there are multiple resource types (for example, multiple vans needed per order).

Is my database designed wrong?

### Update

I tried asking this question in a better way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002457/ef-6-bridge-table-insert-not-working).

Comment: Forgot to mention, the EF didn't create a class for the `Resource_Type_Order` table.  But when I add a new order, it gets populated correctly, but it uses the randomly created ID from the new `ResourceType` entry.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for EF code first is for integer-based primary keys to be populated via identities - check if the PK column is using an identity in the DB

Comment: Still learning sqlserver, but if by `identity` you mean AUTO_INCREMENT, then yes the ID is an `identity`.

Comment: yes, so then the ID you specify when adding a new record will be overwritten when the DB inserts the record due to the identity

Answer (score 0):

> I see new ResourceType records being created with a random ID.

I doubt. I would say that ID Likely is an identity column that is counting up.

Generally it is VERY bad style do assign ID's manually on the client side. What you do when 2 people do inserts at the same time?

EF can handle server side identity columns. And no, the numbers are not random - not if you look at more than one in order they are generated.

Comment: Your right, they are not random, simply counting up.  I don't want to assign the IDs from the client.  The IDs in the ResourceType table are mostly static.  Example ID=1,Van ID=2,Truck, ID=3,Car.  I don't expect those to change.  Order IDs are auto assigned, and I would expect that the `ResourceType_Order` entry should point to an Order ID and have one or more `ResourceTypes`.

Comment: THen basically you must change the setup in the database and EF - EF now thinkks that they are assigned on the server and the server table thinks so, too ;) Start with the proper table definition. The field should not be an identity - and EF should not think it is one. THen you can assign them manually.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  I removed the `identity` from the ID column in the ResourceType table.  Now when I try to insert I get a SQL error of `{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Resource_Type'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Resource_Type'. The duplicate key value is (2).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your database design may be wrong if you want to have multiple types per order. I would use the OrderID and the TypeID like a composite key in the table Resource_TypeOrder.
Something like this:

```
     CREATE TABLE Resource_TypeOrder
     (
     OrderID int FOREIGN KEY(OrderID) REFERENCES Orders(OrderID) NOT NULL,
     TypeID int FOREIGN KEY(TypeID) REFERENCES Resource_Type(TypeID) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(OrderID, TypeID)
     )
```

With this approach you are not going to get any problems.

e.g.
This works fine

```
         var ctx = new TypesEntities();


        Resource_Type type = new Resource_Type();
        type.Name = "Type1";

        ctx.Resource_Type.Add(type);

        Order order = new Order();
        order.Name = "Order1";

        ctx.Orders.Add(order);
        type.Orders.Add(order);

        Order order2 = new Order();
        order2.Name = "Order2";

        ctx.Orders.Add(order2);
        type.Orders.Add(order2);


        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

This code gives you 1 type(i.e. ID=1) with 2 orders (i.e. OrderID=1, OrderID=2), but vice versa works as well (many to many relationship)

I hope that this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

you said "For each order, there are multiple resource types", but in your model, in ResourceType_order table, the orderId column is Pk,  it is not pk