# EF 6 Bridge Table Insert Not Working

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am still trying to learn how to use EF and running into a problem with my bridge table.

When I try to create a new `Order` with associated `Resources`, I get the following SQL error:

```
{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Resource_Type'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Resource_Type'. The duplicate key value is (2).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

### Code Looks like this

```
ResourceType resource = new ResourceType();
resource.ID = 2;
resource.Name = "Van"
order.resourceType().Add(resource)

db.Orders.Add(order);
db.SaveChanges();
```

### Tables look like this

```
--Order table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
[Order_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrdernName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Order_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


--Resource Type table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resource_Type](
[ResourceType_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ResourceType] [varchar] (30) NOT NULL

CONSTRAINT [PK_Resource_Type] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
   [ResourceType_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


--Resource Type To Order table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resource_Type_Order](
[ResourceType_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Order_ID] [int] NOT NULL


CONSTRAINT [PK_Resource_Type_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
   [ResourceType_ID] ASC,
   [Order_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Resource_Type_Order] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_Resource_Type_Order FOREIGN KEY([Order_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders]([Order_ID])
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Resource_Type_Order] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Resource_Type_Order_Resource_Type FOREIGN KEY([ReosurceType_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Resource_Type]([Resource_ID])
GO
```

Am I using the bridge table correctly?  I want my bridge table to look like this, after I add an order (ID=1) with two resources (car ID=1 and van ID=2).

[image: Example tables]

Comment: how are your entities defined

Comment: @Thewads Do you mean the class definitions?  I used VS2013 and DB first to build the model in my MVC app.

Comment: I'm thinking that I may need to override `OnModelCreateing` and manually define the many-to-many relationship?

Comment: What do your entity classes look like yes.